# A simple way to prove that the union of non-disjoint intervals is an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

**Let $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ be intervals. Prove that if $\mathcal{I} \cap \mathcal{J} \neq \varnothing$ then $\mathcal{I} \cup \mathcal{J}$ is an interval.**

I could prove it by cases but the proof is extremly extense and i want to know how to prove it in a shorter or more simple way.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You can edit the question to show us your proof by cases. Then perhaps we can suggest a way to shorten it. But it may be short enough already.

Comment: See my edits to the question for proper MathJax usage. Note that there is a difference between $\cap$ and $\bigcap.$ The latter is used in things like $\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i$ and the former in things like $A\cap B$ and $A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_n.$ And the whole expression $\mathcal I \cap\mathcal J \ne \varnothing$ should be between only one pair of dollar signs, or of double dollar signs, not one for each character separately.

Comment: Intervals are the only (path-)connected subsets of the real line and if two connected sets share a point their union is (path-)connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asserting that $I\cup J$ is an interval means that if $a,b\in I\cup J$ and $c\in\mathbb R$ are such that $a<c<b$, then $c\in I\cup J$. Of course, if $a,b\in I$ or $a,b\in J$, this is trivial. We can assum WLOG that $a\in I$ and $b\in J$. Take $d\in I\cap J$.

1. If $d=c$, there's nothing to prove.
2. If $d<c$ then, since $d,b\in J$ and $J$ is an interval, $c\in J\subset I\cup J$.
3. If $d>c$ then, since $d,a\in I$ and $I$ is an interval, $c\in I\subset I\cup J$.